GeoDjango_Installation_don't_work
In my GeoDjango installation process (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/5.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows), GDAL is an important component.
I followed the recommendations from the Python website by using OSGeo4W. When I run gdalinfo --version (as you can see in the image), Django recommends installing Python 3.12, which I have already done! I have also installed PostgreSQL and PostGIS. However, when I install OSGeo4W, it directly installs GDAL 0.9. I’m not sure why it’s asking for GDAL 0.8 when I run gdalinfo --version.
How can I fix this?
